# Jquery Mobile listview filled with data from mySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, listview, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am trying to create a listview in jquery mobile for my phonegap application that will be filled with values from a 'mares' column in a table within my database.

At present I am using the following code:

**Script Within HTML File**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function makeList() {
    $.post("urlOfFileOnServer.php",
        function(resultfromphp) {
            $('#ulListview').append(resultfromphp);
            $('#ulListview').trigger('create');    
            $('#ulListview').listview('refresh');
    });
}

$("#pageName").live('pagebeforeshow', function(event) {
    makeList();

});
</script>
```

**Tag within HTML Body**

```
<ul id="ulListview"></ul>
```

**PHP file stored on server**

```
<?php

    include_once('db.php');
$sth = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM dates");
$rows = array();
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($sth)) {
    $rows[] = $r;
}
print json_encode($rows);
?>
```

At present no list is diplayed
Any help in getting this to work would be much appreciated, thank you

Answer (score 0):

According to your code, you want to use JSON for your data format.
If so, first what you need is to add header to you response before returning content

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

Try by debugging if your JSON content is returned in correct way.

Answer (score 0):

Try change function `makeList`:

*JS*

```
 function makeList() {
   $.post("urlOfFileOnServer.php",
    function(resultfromphp) {
      var items = [];

      $.each(resultfromphp, function(item,i) {
       items.push('<li>' + item.mares + '</li>'); 
      });
      var list = items.join(' ');

      $('#ulListview').append(list);
   },'json');
 }
```

*HTML*

```
<ul id="ulListview" data-role="listview" data-inset="true"></ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer voodoo, I tried this but it still isn't working.